# La función de correo PHP mail() no envía correo si es dirección de Yahoo

Tags: php, email, servidor

Buenas noches compañeros.
Espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

Lo que ocurre es que tengo un formulario donde se envía un mensaje a un correo electrónico de Yahoo. Cuando se envía un correo con dirección de @gmail o @hotmail el correo llega perfectamente o incluso con cualquier otra dirección. El problema ocurre cuando se envía de una dirección de @yahoo.

Probe cambiando el destino a una cuenta de Gmail y ocurre lo mismo, si se envía de una dirección de @yahoo el mensaje no llega pero me marca que si fue enviado.

Adjunto el código envío PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$affair = $_POST['affair'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$header = 'From: ' . $email . " \r\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
$header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain";


$mensaje = "De: $name \n";
$mensaje .= "Télefono: $phone \n";
$mensaje .= "Correo electrónico: $email \n";
$mensaje .= "Enviado el " . date('d/m/Y')."\n\n";
$mensaje .= " $message ";


$para = 'usuario@yahoo.com';
$asunto = "Mensaje de mi sitio Web: $affair ";

echo (mail($para, $asunto, utf8_decode($mensaje), $header)) ? 'Mensaje enviado. Gracias por tu espera' : 'Mensaje no enviado. Por favor revisa que tu información es correcta';
?>
```

Comment: Has revisado la carpeta SPAM?

Comment: Hola buenas tarde, lo que te puede estar sucediendo,  es que  el servidor de yahoo rechase tus correo por alguna politica de seguridad.  Una solucion seria hacer el envio a travez de otro servidor como el de google el cual te permite conxiones remotas del smtp .

Comment: @Jakala si ya revise pero no llegan ahí tampoco.

Comment: @YoelRodriguez De hecho si probe en otros servidores como hotmail y gmail. En gmail ocurre lo mismo, no llegan los mensajes de Yahoo y en hotmail  si llegan todos. El problema más que nada es porque necesitaba hacerlo para yahoo, ya que el cliente de la página tiene su correo en Yahoo y el sólo maneja ese servidor. Es sólo que ya no se que mas hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente tu servidor esté baneado de Yahoo, recuerda que para que un servidor pueda enviar correos de manera correcta debe cumplir con muchos requisitos, por ejemplo:

- Contar con una firma DKIM
- Contar con registros SPF
- La dirección IP del servidor debe estar permitido como enviador por el registro SPF
- Contar con registros DMARC
- La dirección IP del servidor debe contar con un registro inverso válido según registro SPF y DKIM
- Las cabeceras de envío de correos debe declarar el nombre del servidor
  real

Normalmente todo esto no se hace solo, debes hacerlo tu mismo, si usas cpanel entonces todo esto se realiza de manera casi automática, si has utilizado una instalación manual entonces deberás realizar todas estas modificaciones de manera manual, comenzando por instalar OpenDKIM y crear tus entradas de registros DNS que correspondan.

Recuerda cada cierto tiempo darle un vistazo a tus correos en cola, otra opción es que tu servidor fue atacado y se ha puesto a enviar correos de manera masiva y has caído en alguna lista negra, para saber esto revisar tu dominio y dirección ip en algún sitio de verificación RBL.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ahora comprendo el error no esta en código. Yo estoy utilizando Godaddy como servicio de hosting y dominio, por lo que veo el cpanel es el Plesk pero la verdad desconozco activar esos requerimientos una vez ahí. Ahorita ando investigando los requisitos que mencionas y como activarlos en en cpanel pero no me aparece mucha información. Una duda disculpa ¿Esos requerimientos se pueden activar sin importar el plan de pago del servicio?

Comment: Vi en una pagina algo de que se utilizaba un servicio llamado Doppler Relay para activar el DKIM y SPF pero desconozco más del caso. Tendría que investigar más a fondo para activar esos requerimientos desde mi cpanel Plesk.

Comment: Normalmente cuando agregas el dominio en tu cpanel esos registros se crean de manera automática, puedes darle un vistazo en el menú de dns de cpanel, si utilizas cpanel probablemente no es mucho lo que tengas que hacer, revisa que tu dominio no se encuentre en listas negras RBL https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

Comment: Hola acabo de revisar y mi ip no está en lista negra. Algo curioso ahorita que estoy investigando es que utilice MailTester www.mail-tester.com/ para comprobar es estatus de mi correo enviado desde mi página. Me dice que no cuenta con nada de las DKIM, SPF o DMARC pero cuando revise la ip con la que se envía no es la del dominio sino que es otra ip diferente. Por lo que veo el plan que tengo es de servidor compartido. Es posible que esto sea la causa del problema. Ya que he intentado poner lo del DKIM, SPF y DMARC al dominio en el DNS pero no funciona.